# Gwt shared package

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I currently have domain objects in the client package. These objects are used in the server RPC methods and it all works fine. 
Why do I need a shared package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine because you have imported client packages in server side code. Now the server side is dependent on client packages for the domain objects. So to keep the client side and service side code strictly separated you need to use shared folder.